# Why my horizontal ScrollView is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I´m trying without success to use the `ScrollView` component in React Native, below the code:

```
const width_proportion = '97%';
const height_proportion = '75%';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: '100%'
    },
    image: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: "cover",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    text: {
        color: "grey",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    popup: {
        color: '#CA0',
    },
    box: {
        width: width_proportion,
        height: height_proportion,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
        // position: "absolute",
        marginTop: '5%',
        marginBottom: '3%',
        marginLeft: '2%'
    },
    bottomBox: {

        width: '97%',
        height: 125,
        backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
        marginLeft: '2%',
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginTop: 5,
        padding: 5
    }
});

const MyTheme = {

    colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        background: '#EFA',
        primary: '#000',
        text: '#000',
    },
};

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
                    <Image source={hamburgerMenu} style={{ height: 45, width: 45, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    </Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <ImageBackground source={imgBackground} style={styles.image}>

            <View style={styles.box}>
                </View>

            <ScrollView horizontal={true} >
                <View style={styles.bottomBox}>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bottomBox}>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bottomBox}>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>

            </ImageBackground>

        </View >

    );
}
```

When I set  the `horizontal` property to "true" from `ScrollView`, the component disappears. Only I set `horizontal` to "false" and the `ScrollView` workks fine in Vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your scrollview like this

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    <View style={styles.bottomBox} />
    <View style={styles.bottomBox} />
    <View style={styles.bottomBox} />              
</ScrollView>

bottomBox : {
    width: 40,
    height: 125,
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
    padding: 5,
    marginRight: 10,
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for responding my question,. But, when I insert the View as wrapper my other views and set the ScrollView´s property Horizontal to "true", it´s continue to disappear on the screen. So it´s not works on this mode

Comment: Hey! @Ediberto  I've edited my ans.. try with this styling.. somehow your styling was not working.. might be bcz for the % .. 

please note :    horizontal={true} not  horizontal={"true"} as horizontal accept only boolean, else it will take false

Comment: Great! Now works fine! The ScrollView rolls in horizontal mode!
Thanks!!!

Comment: Awsm... happy to help :) .. You can accept my answer if you are satisfied.